# Extracting results from MarkLogic database using java client api

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am new to the MarkLogic database. My use case is:

I am trying to connect to the MarkLogic database using Java client api. I have my JSON documents stored in the database, which has tradingDate ( of type date ) as one of the fields. Now I want to fetch all the documents whose tradingDate is less than a particular date.

Could some one please let me know how to proceed further?

Comment: You should include some example code you have already tried. SO in not a free coding service.

Comment: Kiras has re-asked this question with more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850049/extracting-data-from-marklogic-db-using-java-client-api-when-fetching-one-docume

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into:

- [MLCP](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) export with a transform,
- or into using something like [CORB2](http://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below sample and make it working using the query by example in marklogic:-

```
val queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();

var rawHandle: StringHandle = new StringHandle

rawHandle.withFormat(Format.JSON).

set("{\"$query\":  {\"tradingDate\": { \"$le\":\""+ date + "\"}, \"$filtered\": true}}");

var querydef: RawQueryByExampleDefinition  = queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(rawHandle);  

querydef.setCollections("Collection Name");

jsonDocMgr.search(querydef, 1);
```

But do you suggest any more good options to work on?